# Pandas merge only when the value of a column is different across dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes:
df_1

| Unique_ID | Species | Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A |  |
| 2 | B | Mutant |
| 3 | A |  |
| 4 | B | Mutant |
| 5 | C | Mutant23 |

df_2

| Species | Type |
| --- | --- |
| A | Wildtype |
| B | Mutant |
| C | Mutant2 |

I want to merge both dataframes so that the type column in df_1 is updated with the data in df_2, so for each species update the type. However I would rather only do it for the species that are missing the data or have different data across both dataframes.

In the example species A is missing the data, and species C needs to be updated from Mutant23 to Mutant2.

And then I want a list of the species for which the type value in df1 did not match the type value in df2.

My current approach was:

```
for specie in df_2['Species'].unique():
    df_1.loc[df_1['Species'] == specie, 'Type'] = df_2.loc[df_2['Species'] == specie, 'Type'].tolist()[0]
```

But I want to avoid using for loops.
Thanks

Comment: [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html).

Comment: I'd say even just `map` Species -> Type since you basically don't care what data already exists.

Comment: I do care about the data that already exists, if the data is the same across both I want to know because then another calculation is done for the ones where data did not match.

Comment: combine_first doesn't look like it updates the value if it's different across dataframes, it only fills null values

Comment: Then you are looking for [`update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html)?